# How can I add a sequence to the left of a materialized view in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

I have a materialized view as follows:

```
|product_type|
--------------
shoes
clothing
electronics
..100's more
```

I'd like to create the view instead in a way that each product type has a corresponding ID. So the view should look as follows:

```
| ID | product_type|
--------------------
1   | shoes
2   | clothing
3   | electronics
100 | ..100's more
```

SQL used to create the view was:

```
select distinct(product_type) from items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by product_type) as my_id
```

However, if you need a unique number per `product_type` -- and one that is stable over time -- I would suggest using an `identity` column in a "product types" table.

For your particular example, I would suggest:

```
select row_number() over (order by product_type), product_type
from items
group by product_type;
```

Comment: don't need unique number that is stable over time, just a simple sequence from 1 to N should suffice.

I tried the following but getting a syntax error:
`select row_number() over (order by product_type) row_num, distinct(product_type) as product_type from items`

Comment: @sambehera . . . `distinct` is not a function.  That is causing your syntax error.

Comment: now using this `select row_number() over (order by product_type) row_num, (product_type) as product_type from items` it executes but I'm getting product_types for ALL items which are over a million instead of just the unique product types..

Comment: @sambehera . . . You are not using the query that I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need distinct product_type and then you want sequence number on it.

Use the following query:

```
Select product_type,
       row_number() over (order by product_type) row_num
  From (Select distinct product_type
          From items) t
```